# Difference between DBMS and Database server

Tags: database, rdbms, mysql, database-server

Could someone here please clarify the difference between a 'DBMS' and 'Database Server' please?
And also, is 'MySQL', a name of a database query language or a name of a DBMS?

Comment: DBMS is the software. Server is the hardware. Search wikipedia for these terms.

Comment: @Bohemian, thanks for that reply. Server is hardware? I'm bit confused now. I know server is a software installed on a host system's OS. What my question meant was that - Is installing database server on host's OS is = to installing DBMS on that host. Are DBMS and Database server terms one and the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBMS stands for Database Management System (see wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)
MySQL is a DBMS and it has a server component and a client component, each can run on different or on the same computer.

MySQL, as most DBMS, use SQL as query language (which has been normalized), but also adds some custom queries (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/extensions-to-ansi.html)

Answer (score 0):

DBMS - "database management system" which is a server side of client-server model software. So it is the same as "Database Server". Sometimes the server may also mean a computer where the server part of database installed.

MySQL is a DBMS, but it also has its language slightly different from other SQL languages, like there are others: Transact-SQL, PL-SQL, SQL-92... So you may say that MYSQL is a language.

Answer (score 0):

Term Database server can refer to hardware but in your case database server means an instance of DBMS. 
Means that MYSQL is a DBMS , it can create and manage database servers. Lets say I have two database servers one is on localhost and another is on some ip say 192.168.1.100 . here, both are database servers and both servers are based on MYSQL DBMS